# ReactJS- downloading a pdf file "Failed - no file"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have written a React Component to download a pdf file using the achor tag of the file. I'm getting an error `Failed- No file`.

```
import React from 'react'

const Links = ()=>
        <div className='github-link'>
             <a href="https://github.com/" rel='noopener noreferrer'  alt="github link"
     target='_blank'><strong>View my GitHub here!</strong></a>
     <a href="../resume/resume.pdf" download><strong>Download my Resume!</strong></a>
        </div>



export default Links
```

I have my resume pdf in my src directory inside a directory called resume. The file I want to download is called resume.pdf

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Were you able to find a fix for it?

Answer (score 6):

Easy fix is to put the pdf file in your `public` folder and set `href="resume.pdf"`.

You can also create a folder named `resume` in your `public` and put the pdf file inside your `resume` folder.

```
<a href="/resume/resume.pdf" download><strong>Download my Resume!</strong></a>
```

Comment: it says-- Not allowed to load local resource

Answer (score -1):

The trick is to **Link** it to the file which would be stored in the public folder.

Then :

1. Create a folder in the Public Directory of Your react app called "files"(*it doesn't need to be called files in your public directory but for this example, you can do it like this*).
2. Store the file within the folder
3. `<Link to="/files/file.pdf">Download</Link>`