# How to put a file in my website server available for download

Tags: html, reactjs, download

I'm trying to implement a click and download functionality in react.
I tried using

```
<a href="/files/myfile.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

but when the user clicks on it the download would display "Failed - No file".
I searched many articles and the answer I found is

```
<a href="http://example.com/files/myfile.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

So now my question is how can I upload the file to the webserver in react, so when the user goes to that url they can have a file available for download.

Comment: How you make your web server serve static files is entirely down to what web server you are using. (Unless you are asking how to upload stuff to `example.com` specifically as opposed to "your own server for which `example.com` is a placeholder" in which case: you don't, use your own server instead)

Comment: Your Question is novice and I suggest you revise the [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] guide first 
Anyway, I believe increasing your knowledge in servers is essential to help you formulate a better questions as most answers are out of scope 
This is a simple article that should help you get a better grasp of what you want [https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/how-to-upload-files-server/]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file needs to be available on the webserver and if it's a public file this file needs to have Read rights set to Public. Be careful with this and not set write rights to public. How you get your file there is very dependant on your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer from this post: [ReactJS- downloading a pdf file "Failed - no file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56348979/reactjs-downloading-a-pdf-file-failed-no-file)

I just need to put the files to download in the public folder

Answer (score 0):

I use a library called: js-file-download, it helps with downloading any type of file.

Here is the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-file-download

Answer (score -2):

You can use below template which can generate link of file which can be downloadable.

```
  <a href="/images/ImageName.jpg" download>
    <img src="/images/ImageName.jpg" alt="Image">
  </a>
```

Comment: The question is asking how to make the URL work, not how to get the HTML to do particular things with the URL.

Answer (score -2):

You have to put the pdf file in a folder. lets assume the folder is in the main directory and the folder name is pdf-folder and the pdf filename is my-pdf.pdf,

Then you can do this:

```html
<a href="pdf-folder/mypdf.pdf"> The pdf-file</a>
```

And if this doesn't work you should try implementing javascript and then use createObjectUrl.

Comment: The question is asking how to make the URL work, not how to get the HTML to do particular things with the URL. (And that's a hugely over-complicated approach to getting the browser to download something anyway).

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Give me a sec let me edit my answer

Comment: I'm not sure how editing the answer will help; the question seems to lack enough detail to be answerable at all in its current state.

Comment: Re edit: You're making a lot of assumptions about how the server works.

Comment: Try implementing javascript and use createObjectUrl method to create a url link for it. With that you can add the link to the href